# Date time String + TimeZone

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, time

I have a String representation of a local date time, and a Java TimeZone.

I am trying to get output in the format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ but I can't figure out how to create a Calendar or JodaTime object with the correct date time and timezone.  How do you get a TimeZone converted to a value that can be parsed by SimpleDateFormat 'Z' or 'z'?

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
String startDate = "08/14/2014 15:00:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(startDate));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");
```

and

```
sdfZ.format(cal.getTime())
```

returns

```
08/14/2014 15:00:00-0400
```

which is `EST`.

Is the only workaround to create a Calendar or Joda DateTime and set the individual year/month/day/hour/min values by parsing the string "08/14/2014 15:00:00" ?

Comment: Please explain more clearly the values you are expecting.

Comment: In the example above I am trying to get '08/14/2014 15:00:00-0500' which represents the date time '08/14/2014 15:00:00' in CST.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar `getTime()` - Returns a Date object representing this Calendar's time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch(01-01-1970 00:00 GMT)") irrespective of which timezone you are displaying.  But hour of day in different TimeZone will be different. `get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

You should try

```
sdfZ.setTimeZone(tz);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Setting the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat before the cal.setTime(sdf.parse(startDate)) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ) ;
String output = zdt.toInstant().toString() ;
```

> 2016-12-03T10:15:30Z

## java.time

Both the java.util.Calendar class and the Joda-Time library have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Call `toString` to generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. For example, `2011-12-03T10:15:30Z`. This format is good for serializing date-time values for data storage or exchange.

```
String output = instant.toString();  // Ex: 2011-12-03T10:15:30Z
```

## Time zone

Assign a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

As a shortcut, you can skip over using `Instant`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Calling `toString` on `ZonedDateTime` gets you an extended version of standard ISO 8601 format where the name of the time zone is appended in square brackets. For example, `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`.

```
String output = zdt.toString(); //  Ex: 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

The `DateTimeFormatter` class has a predefined formatter constant for your desired output: [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

```
String output zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).